# Splitting line by comma from CSV file containing field with comma in it

Tags: java, csv, split

I'm trying to write a piece of code to populate a database to contain old cars. I have a CSV file containing all the relevant information that I require, such as year, engine size, description. However, when I try to split the lines, the commas within the description are picked up, and the code proceeds to move onto the next column. I understand I could remove all commas but this seems counter productive if there was a vast amount of data. Is there a way I can keep the commas, and tell my program to only proceed to the next column if it reach's a comma that does not have a space after it? I have attached some code before.

```
private static void populateCars(Connection connection) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileReader carData= new FileReader("cars.csv");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(carData)) {
        String line;
        br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitLineInArrays = line.split(",")

            String carName= splitLineInArrays[0];
            String CarModel= splitLineInArrays[1];
            int EngineSize = Integer.parseInt(splitLineInArrays[2].trim());
            String Description = splitLineInArrays[3];
            String CountryOfOrigion = splitLineInArrays[4];
            insertDataForCars(connection, carName, carModel, engineSize, description, country);
        }
    } catch (SQLException | IOException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The CSV file looks like this:

Austin,Maxi,1750,The Austin Maxi is a medium-sized, 5-door hatchback family car that was produced by Austin and later British Leyland between 1969 and 1981. It was the first British five-door hatchback.,UK

Comment: `line.split(",")` -> `line.split(",(?! )")`

Comment: 1) Don't parse CSV yourself, use an appropriate and battle-tested library for this, 2) your CSV sample doesn't seem to quote text containing commas. How is any CSV parser supposed to infer that the comma separates another field, or is part of a value?